# Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension. Let $M$ be an intermediate field of $L/K$ and $L/M$ and $M/K$ be a Galois extension.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension.
Let $M$ be an intermediate field of $L/K$ and $L/M$ and $M/K$ be a Galois extension.

From Galois correspondence, ${\rm Gal}(M/K)$ is subgroup of ${\rm Gal}(L/K)$.

But what about ${\rm Gal}(L/M)$?

I heard this is subgroup of ${\rm Gal}(L/K)$ from my teacher, but I think this is isomorphic to the quotient group ${\rm Gal}(L/K)/{\rm Gal}(M/K)$ and not even a subset of ${\rm Gal}(L/K)$.

What can we say about ${\rm Gal}(L/M)$? Isn't it a quotient group and not a subgroup?

Comment: No, $\mathrm{Gal}(L/M)$ is a **subgroup** of $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$, the subgroup of automorphisms of $L$ that fix $M$. $M$ is Galois over $K$ precisely when this subgroup is normal, and in that case $\mathrm{Gal}(M/K)$ is a **quotient** of $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$, precisely by moding out by $\mathrm{Gal}(L/M)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $L/K$ is a Galois extension, and $M$ is any intermediate field, then $L/M$ is also Galois, and ${\rm Gal}(L/M)$ is a subgroup of ${\rm Gal}(L/K)$, by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory.

If it so happens that $M/K$ is a Galois extension, then $Gal(L/M)$ is normal in ${\rm Gal}(L/K)$ (and vice versa), and we also have $${\rm Gal}(L/K)\,/\,{\rm Gal}(L/M)\cong{\rm Gal}(M/K).$$